# ADOQuery.Filter not working with LIKE

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7, ms-access-2003

I have a query in ADOQuery2. Now I want have a filter for that so:

```
  ADOQuery2.Filter := 'where Fname like ' + QuotedStr(Txt_Search.Text + '*');
  ADOQuery2.Filtered := true;
```

but it throws this exception: (`*` in like statement is for Access instead of `%`)

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the LIKE operator *from within Access itself* the asterisk `*` is the correct wildcard character, but for ADO connections from other applications (like yours) you should actually be using the "standard" percent `%` wildcard character for SQL.

Comment: aaaah thanks for this. as usual, I should have asked google/stack overflow way sooner, but nooo, it takes me at least an hour to 'admit that I need help'...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works fine

```
if  Txt_Search.Text<> '' then
begin
    ADOQuery2.Filter := 'where Fname like '+QuotedStr(Txt_Search.Text+'*');
    ADOQuery2.Filtered := true;
end;
```

or

```
if  Txt_Search.Text<> '' then
begin
    ADOQuery2.Filter := 'Fname like '+QuotedStr(Txt_Search.Text+'%');
    ADOQuery2.Filtered := true;
end;
```